# Correct timezone for AttributeType::DateTime in CP

Tags: plugin-development, localization

I've written a plugin that stores records in it's own table. I can see that the `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` fields are stored in UTC.

When I want to display them in a CP template, I'm using `populateModel` and my model contains `'dateCreated' => AttributeType::DateTime`.

If I output this with `{{ entry.dateCreated|dateTime }}` then I'm still getting UTC time and not BST (the Timezone in Settings).

If I use `{{ entry.dateCreated|date('d M Y H:i', 'Europe/London') }}` then it's correct.

Is there any way to get the date with the correct timezone set automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing at the moment (should be cleaner in the upcoming Craft 3), but for now, if you use `{{ entry.dateCreated|date }}`, it should take the timezone into account and display the correct time.

Comment: Thanks Brad, it is a bit confusing. I was originally using the `{{ entry.dateCreated|datetime }}` filter which shows UTC. If I use `{{ entry.dateCreated|date('d M Y H:i') }}` then I get the local output.